# Finding and Changing Index of Array Java OOP

Tags: java, oop

How can you make a method to find the specific row / column and change it, for example I want to find 1,3,13 and change it to 2,1,1?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     array2 ob=new array();

    int[][] data = {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {6, 7}};
    int[][] data2 = {{8, 9}, {10, 11}, {12, 13}};


    System.out.println("Data a: ");
    ob.setArray(data);
    ob.showarray(ob.getArray());
    System.out.println("Data b: ");
    ob.setArray(data2);
    ob.showaray(ob.getArray());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect a specific row you can try a loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i, 0] == oldSpecificRowValue){
     data[i, 0] = newSpecificRowValue;
  }
}
```

and if you detect a specific value on a column, the example becomes

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i, 1] == oldSpecificColumnValue){
     data[i, 1] = newSpecificColumnValue;
  }
}
```

The first example scans the 2D array and if the row value is equal to a specific value then the value is replaced with a new one. The second example does the same thing using the values on the columns.

As you asked a method, everything can be encapsulated by a method like

```
private void changeRowValue(double[] data, double oldVal, double newVal){
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      if(data[i, 0] == oldVal){
         data[i, 0] = newVal;
      }
    }
 }
```